# The effect is twice as big for females as it is for males. -formality

Tags: comparisons

> The effect is twice as big for females as it is so for males.
>
> The effect is twice as big for females as it is for males.
>
> The effect is twice as big for females as for males.

I am struggling to select the best sentence for an academic essay, a formal piece of writing. Can I omit *it is (so)*, or would to do so be too informal? If I select one of the other options, should I include *so*? http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/common-verbs/do

> Do so is more formal than do on its own

Comment: Don't pick #1 - it can mean that the effect is twice as big for females *because* it is (also) twice as big (whatever that means) for males.

Comment: #1 is impossible. The other two are fine and display varying degrees of reduction as is normal with comparative clauses.

Comment: 'big' is slightly informal. Use 'large' instead.

Answer (score 1):

The first is too wordy.

The third is unclear because it is missing words.

The second is juuuuust right.

Answer (score -1):

**First**, as Lawrence mentioned above,

> The effect is twice as big for females as it is so for males.

can be read as

> The effect is twice as big for females, as it is so for males.

That is, the effect doubled owing to something else that was just mentioned being true for males.

The other two sentences are both correct and semantically identical. The only reason to opt for the first one is to pad your word count, though, which will annoy some teachers.

**Second**, if you're actually trying to sound more formal, don't use phrases with several short Germanic words when you can use a single Latinate word to mean the same thing. "Become twice as big" is "double"; "be twice as big" is "be double".

**Third**, when possible, use the actual noun instead of substantifying an adjective. If this is about humans, "females" are much more commonly called "women", and "woman" is a much less politically loaded term at the moment. With animals, there may be appropriate terms (*mares*, *hens*, &c.) but they'll probably sound less scientific than "females" since they're usually Germanic and associated with farms and ranches instead of grant proposals.

Comment: Your third point might be valid, depending on social setting, if we are talking about human males and females. If we are talking about a population of lab rats, it is not.

Comment: @oerkelens: Valid point.

Answer (score -1):

Either of these might be clearer in conveying your meaning.

The effect for females is double that seen for males.

For females the effect is double, when compared with males.

Comment: The second alternative is clumsy and unnecessarily more complex than the first which is admirable.